# How to get the diameter of a line in an image?

Tags: image, matlab, line

as you know I am working on images, at this moment I am facing the following problem, I do not know how to measure the diameter of the line that is observed in the image that I attached, I could apply a little the theorem of Pythagoras, but I do not know if it is possible to do it in an image, for example in this case the image has a thick line, but in case the line is thinner than can be done?

[image: Example image]

I would like to know the diameter when the line is alone, because it is obvious that when there is a cross the diameter will change, I show it in the next image.

[image: diameter]

Comment: Are you actually trying to find intersections really? Maybe consider skeletonising and looking for intersections rather than jumps in line thickness.

Answer (score 1):

Here are simple hacks for when the resolution and thickness are "large enough":

at a given point on the line where you want to estimate the thickness you can do one of 2 things:

1) span out a line from that point at every angle between 0 and 180 and find the line that results in the shortest overlap with your original line, it will be the thickness

2) span out a circle from that point, whenever the circle is not overlapping anymore with the line, re-center it to have full overlap. When it is impossible to re-center it anymore such that you have full overlap, then the diameter where you still managed to have an overlap is your best estimate of line thickness

Answer (score 1):

One way to display an estimate of the line thickness is to use [`bwdist`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/bwdist.html) to calculate the distance to the nearest edge for each point in the line, then use [`imdilate`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/imdilate.html) to smooth the maximum values (running along the center of the line) out across the width of the line. You can then select a point on the line to see its approximate diameter (which will be off a bit near transitions between diameters, like at joins). Here's an example:

```
img = imread('qGs5t.png');            % Load RGB image
bw = ~im2bw(img);                     % Convert to black and white and invert
bw = imclose(bw, strel('disk', 3));   % Morphological close to remove noise
distImage = bwdist(~bw);              % Distance transform
maxDist = double(max(distImage(:)));  % Find maximum distance measure
diamImage = 2.*bw.*imdilate(distImage, strel('disk', floor(maxDist)));  % Dilate and mask

imagesc(diamImage);            % Display image
colorbar;                      % Display color bar
dcmObj = datacursormode(gcf);  % Create data cursor object...
set(dcmObj, 'Enable', 'on');   % ... and enable to select points
```

And here's the image with a point selected (the "Index" value is the approximate diameter):

[image]

Comment: But if I want it to be automatic, it extracts the diameter of the lines by itself, then save it in a list or a hashmap (where it knows which line identifier is and what thickness it has)

Comment: @AlexZ: If you want to automate it, you're going to have to be more specific about how you want it done. Are you going to provide points along the lines where the diameter is to be measured? Do you want lines broken at the points where they are joined and a separate diameter measurement done for each segment? Should the diameter of the line be reported as the maximum or average diameter along its length?